# Unable to find championship races

Tags: forza-horizon-2

So I was running through the championship races, and for some reason I can no longer see races to enter after I select enter race and choose my car. The map has no race icons at all.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After you finish 4 races you select a new championship and/or car at a Festival hub for the road trip to go next, use your map to help you get to your next destination.

You can try a few things:

open up your map and make sure your filters are set up properly (Left Bumper brings up the filter menu)

If you have Kinect ask ANNA for help by saying "Anna" and then "continue road trip" when she responds. After that, she will route you to the nearest event.

Unless of course you've finished all 168 championships... then no more races will show up